# How to transpose columns to rows of a table dynamically using a DB2 sql code where columns may increase over time and no need to change the code?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table where columns will eventually increase over time. I want to write a query that transposes the table even later columns increases and no need to add extra line of code to achieve it. I need to transpose those columns where value is 'Y'

```
Eg: Source data on day 1
| Emp_ID | DOC 1 | DOC 2 |
| ------ |-------|-------|
| 001    | Y     |Y      |
| 002    | N     |Y      |

Day 1 output
| Emp_ID | Transposed | 
| ------ |-------|
| 001    | DOC 1 |
| 001    | DOC 2 |
| 002    | DOC 2 |
```

now eventually the columns may increase, and want the same query block to handle it without any change in code, can we?

```
Source data on day 2
| Emp_ID | DOC 1 | DOC 2 | DOC 3|
| ------ |-------|-------|------|
| 001    | Y     |Y      |N     |
| 002    | N     |Y      |Y     |
| 003    | N     |N      |N     |

Day 2 output
| Emp_ID | Transposed | 
| ------ |-------|
| 001    | DOC 1 |
| 001    | DOC 2 |
| 002    | DOC 2 |
| 002    | DOC 3 |

**Note have considered only docs having Y as a value. Thanks in advance**
```

Comment: You may generate a query dynamically with either a table function or a stored procedure returning a result set. Both methods would use the syscat.columns system view to get a column list of given table. Which method do you prefer?

Comment: thanks @MarkBarinstein, I may prefer a table function.

Comment: but can you help on this, am struggling to construct the logic.

Comment: Do you have some naming rule on how to select the columns needed for transposing based on their names? For example, `colname like 'DOC%'` or `colname <> 'EMP_ID'`. All the columns with name satisfied such a condition are considered for transposing.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein,  No naming rules required, the only ask is to transpose columns apart from EMP_ID and get the column name as transposed value for that EMP_ID, where DOC was 'Y'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct the following statement dynamically for given base table
`MYSCHEMA.MYTAB (EMP_ID INT, DOC1 CHAR, ..., DOCn CHAR)`:

```
SELECT T.EMP_ID, V.COLNAME
FROM 
  MYSCHEMA.MYTAB T
, (
SELECT COLNAME
FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'MYSCHEMA' AND TABNAME = 'MYTAB' AND COLNAME <> 'EMP_ID' AND TYPENAME LIKE '%CHAR%'
  ) V
WHERE
   V.COLNAME = 'DOC1' AND T.DOC1 = 'Y'
...
OR V.COLNAME = 'DOCn' AND T.DOCn = 'Y'
```

The statement has dynamic `WHERE` part only. The sub-select on `SYSCAT.COLUMNS` returns all the table columns to transpose (all table columns except `EMP_ID`).
The following `SELECT INTO` statement inside the table function generates the final statement needed for whatever number of such columns.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MYFUNC ()
RETURNS TABLE (EMP_ID INT, TRANSPOSED VARCHAR (128))
BEGIN
  DECLARE V_SQL VARCHAR (4000);
  DECLARE V_EMP_ID INT;
  DECLARE V_TRANSPOSED VARCHAR (128);
  DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5);
  DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;
  
    SELECT 
     'SELECT T.EMP_ID, V.COLNAME '
  || 'FROM ' 
  || '  MYSCHEMA.MYTAB T '
  || ', ( '
  || 'SELECT COLNAME '
  || 'FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS '
  || 'WHERE TABSCHEMA = ''MYSCHEMA'' AND TABNAME = ''MYTAB'' AND COLNAME <> ''EMP_ID'' AND TYPENAME LIKE ''%CHAR%'''
  || '  ) V '
  || 'WHERE '
  || LISTAGG ('V.COLNAME = ''' || COLNAME || ''' AND T.' || COLNAME || ' = ''Y''', ' OR ')
  INTO V_SQL
  FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'MYSCHEMA' AND TABNAME = 'MYTAB' AND COLNAME <> 'EMP_ID' AND TYPENAME LIKE '%CHAR%';

  PREPARE S1 FROM V_SQL;
  OPEN C1;
  L1: LOOP 
    FETCH C1 INTO V_EMP_ID, V_TRANSPOSED;
    IF SQLSTATE = '02000' THEN LEAVE L1; END IF;
    PIPE (V_EMP_ID, V_TRANSPOSED);
  END LOOP L1;
  CLOSE C1;
  RETURN;
END@
```

Comment: so once the function is created, i should add the table name to the function to get the output. like ```select * from myfunc(mytable)```??

Comment: The table name is hardcoded in the function body at the moment. So, you need `SELECT * FROM TABLE (MYFUNC ())`.

Comment: what LOOP parameter should i pass? the function query when am running in my DB2 gives error

Comment: There are no any parameters needed to pass anywhere. If you have some error, then please, edit your question with the following info: exact `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE FUNCTION` statements, full error code and message text you get.